# Vim: How to detect type of range within a command?

Tags: vim

Given this...

```
function s:MyFn()
endfunction

command -range MyCommand :call s:MyFn()
```

...how can I tell the difference between the type of range specified to a command (or a function that it calls)? Specifically, how do I tell the difference between a range specified as a pair of line numbers, and a range specified as a pair of marks (usually '<'>). In all my attempts and things I have read, this information seems to get lots as soon as the command is called.

I checked out the following, which sort-of get close, but nether seems to get to the nub of this problem;-

[How to detect existence of Visual selection in VimL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520714/)

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/

I find that if I do this...

```
function s:MyFn(range)
  if a:range == 0
    " No range specified
  elseif a:range == 1
    " Single line specified
  else
    " a:range == 2
  endif
endfunction

command -range MyCommand :call s:MyFn(<range>)
```

This at least solves part of the problem. But in the case of `a:range == 2`, I can't find a way of determining whether the range is a pair of line numbers or a pair of marks (usually, but not necessarily, from a visual selection). If the visual selection was line-wise then the distinction is largely academic. But the distinction matters for character-wise and block-wise visual selections. If I KNOW that a visual selection is in effect then I can work out the type of selection it is. The root problem is detecting whether a visual selection was in effect at all; I cannot just assume that a visual selection was used and use the `'<` and `'>` markers because the range could have been specified as two line numbers and the visual selection markers could be just left-over from a previous (unrelated) use

Comment: All ex commands are designed to operate on lines and so all ranges are converted to lines before processing.  If you don't want to operate linewise, you probably don't want to use the range functionality of `command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range is expanded to a pair of line numbers *before* being consumed by a command or function so the original range is effectively lost by the time you consume its expanded value.

`:help getcmdline()` can be used to… get the raw command line, range included, but it can only be used in a command-line mode mapping so you will have to be a bit creative. Here is a quick and dirty snippet to get you started:

```
" save the current range in a global variable
" insert the name of your custom command for further typing
function! FirstStep()
    let g:my_range = getcmdline()
    return 'MyCommand'
endfunction

" the actual implementation of the desired functionality
" do what you have to do with g:my_range
function! SecondStep()
    if g:my_range == "'<,'>"
        echo "range is purely visual"
    elseif g:my_range =~ '\d\+,\d\+'
        echo "range is purely numerical"
    else
        echo "range is neither purely visual nor purely numerical"
        echo "support for other ranges not yet implemented"
    endif
endfunction

" expression mapping
" inserts the result of FirstStep() in the command-line
cnoremap <expr> MyCommand FirstStep()

" the actual command that calls the actual function
" that actually implements the desired functionality
command! -range=% MyCommand call SecondStep()
```

It looks like this:

[image: example]

Comment: A cunning idea! Thank you. I think this is the best I'll manage - it very much looks like doing what I want to do directly is simply not supported. I checked further and found that even the inbuilt ":yank" gets it wrong for visual-block selection; it yanks the entire lines and not just the visual block.

Comment: `:yank` doesn't "get it wrong". All Ex commands operate on lines—and only lines—by design. If anything, expecting an Ex command to not operate on lines _is_ "getting it wrong".

Comment: Granted - bad choice of words. I accept that what I am trying to do is "wrong", but I don't know how else to achieve it without creating many many key mappings that will be difficult to remember

Comment: FWIW, you didn't really explain what you are trying to do, only how you considered doing it. If you add a reasonably precise description of your goal and some context, *maybe* we can suggest alternative strategies?

Comment: What I am trying to do is add a "paste" option to my DrawX https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5915 plugin. I want to be able to (optionally) indicate a visual-block area and then paste into it. I want options for the "paste" operation to include "cutout" (eliminate surrounding whitespace), "back-to-front", "upside-down" options plus an option (4 values) to indicate which part of the clip to paste. Oh, and pref. also the src registr. I have actually got it working - it's just the user interface I am trying to sort out. But it's the combination of options that is getting in the way

Answer (score 1):

After you've pressed `:` (by key or by mapping) you already got into Command-line mode effectively abandoning any previous (be it Visual or Normal) mode. And so there's no way for your command / function to tell the difference between "get here from Visual or from other mode".

In fact, you have two options: either make a command always to use last visual mode (silently ignoring any range passed on command line); or start from a Visual mode mapping (maybe with "expr" or "cmd" etc.).

Comment: A mapping won't work; it has to be a command because I need to pass a number of parameters to it as well. I suppose what I need to get hold of is the bit between the : and the command - eg, given <code>:`<,`>MyCommand</code> ...I need the <code>"'<,'>"</code> bit but before vim converts it into a start/end line range

Comment: @Rich You can `input()` some stuff from inside of a mapping too. But having both a command, a selection and "**a number** of parameters more" looks to me as bad design.

Comment: It may be a bad design :-) but it needs to work on a visual selection and there are 32 combinations of options so it's impractical to make key mappings for them all